# How do I split on spaces, keeping spaces in quotes and not lose my equals

Tags: c#, regex

I am no good with RegEx so not real familiar with what is going on in this code I borrowed.  I want to split the following String:

```
CHARM CARD_SLOT=1 IO_SUBSYSTEM="CHARMS" CONTROLLER="CIOC-CB3-IO" DEFINITION="CHMIO_DO_24_VDC_HIGH-SIDE_CHARM"
```

So that is in individual strings like:  **(What I want to return)**

```
 CHARM CARD_SLOT=1
 IO_SUBSYSTEM="CHARMS"
 CONTROLLER="CIOC-CB3-IO"
 DEFINITION="CHMIO_DO_24_VDC_HIGH-SIDE_CHARM"
```

I am using this code:

```
while (null != (workString = s.ReadLine()))
{                                        
  RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
  Regex regex = new Regex(@"((""((?<token>.*?)(?<!\\)"")|(?<token>[\w]+))(\s)*)", options);                                        
  var result = (from Match m in regex.Matches(workString)
  where m.Groups["token"].Success
  select m.Groups["token"].Value).ToList();
  foreach (string o in result)
    {
       if (!o.Contains("{") || !o.Contains("}"))
         {
           endResult = endResult + "\r\n" + o;
           Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", "\r\n" + o);
         }
    }                                        
 }
```

**What I am currently returning**

```
CHARM
CARD_SLOT
1
IO_SUBSYSTEM
CHARMS
CONTROLLER
CIOC-CB3-IO
DEFINITION
CHMIO_DO_24_VDC_HIGH-SIDE_CHARM
```

Comment: Try `Regex.Matches(s, @"([^=]+)=(\S+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => new[] {m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value})`, see http://ideone.com/yVIOCp. Or maybe even try with [`([^=\s][^=]*)=(\S+)`](http://ideone.com/f98s8P) regex.

Comment: If you want `CHARM CARD_SLOT=1` on a single line, then you're not splitting on all spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches your example:

```
var pattern = @"(\w[\w ]+=(?:""[^""]+""|[^ ]+))+";

var optionsList = Regex.Matches(src, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Both yours and AmoT worked, but AmoT's pattern was truncating anything within quotes that had more than one word.  Your's worked perfect so for that I will marks you corrects.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this pattern should work:

```
  pattern = @"[^=]+=[^=]+(\s|.$)"; //matches with spaces
  pattern = @"[^=\s]+=[^=]+(?=(\s|.$))"; //matches without spaces
```

my idea is to take `=` and "look around" on both sides (especially right side).
In both pattern I look whether it ends with " " or it is very end of string. And finally I remove matched spaces by using lookahead feature as we don't need them.